# What is wrong with my java method code? - Stacks

Tags: java, methods, iterator, stack, peek

I have spent the last few hours creating a method that will take null elements from stack s1, and place them into s2. The class should then print the stacks. The method is as follows

```
import net.datastructures.ArrayStack;
import net.datastructures.Stack;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;

public class Stacks {
    public static <E> void compress(Stack<E> s1, Stack<E> s2) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
            s1.peek();
            if (s1.peek() == null) {
                s1.pop();        
            } else if (s1.peek() == !null) {
                s1.pop();
                s2.push();
                counter++;
            }
            for (counter=10;counter>s1.size(); counter--){
            }
            s2.pop();
            s1.push();
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test method compress
        Stack<Integer> S1 = new ArrayStack<Integer>(10);
        S1.push(2);
        S1.push(null);
        S1.push(null);
        S1.push(4);
        S1.push(6);
        S1.push(null);
        Stack<Integer> s2 = new ArrayStack<Integer>(10);
        s2.push(7);
        s2.push(9);
        System.out.println("stack S1: " + S1);
        // prints: "stack S: [2, null, null, 4, 6, null]"
        System.out.println("stack s2: " + s2);
        // prints: "stack X: [7, 9]"
        compress(S1, s2);
        System.out.println("stack S1: " + S1);
        // should print: "stack S: [2, 4, 6]"
        System.out.println("stack s2: " + s2);
        // should print: "stack X: [7, 9]"
    }
}
```

Eclipse is giving me errors for both peek() and push() methods; it allows the pop() method. It was my understanding that these methods are inherited? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are the errors messages, please could you add to your question?

Answer (score 4):

```
else if (s1.peek() == !null)
```

That is not correct.  Use this:

```
else if (s1.peek() != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    if (s1.peek() == null) {
        s1.pop();

    } else if (s1.top() == !null) {
        s1.pop();
        s2.push();

        counter++;
    }
```

Should be:

```
    if (s1.top() == null) {
        s1.pop();

    } else {
        s2.push(s1.pop());

        counter++;
    }
```

You don't need to double check `s1.peek()`is not null. Plus, `!null` is not the correct syntax.

I edited my answer to use `top()` instead of `peek()` and to `pop()` `s1` into `s2`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the error with the comparison, you have a few more syntax errors:

`push()` requires a parameter: what are you pushing onto the stack? Even if it's `null` it'll still need to be `s1.push(null)`. If it's what you're `pop()`-ing, you need to assign the result of `pop()` to something -- right now it's being lost to the ether.

The object you're using (net.datastructures.Stack) doesn't have a `peek()` method; instead it has `top()` which performs the same function.

Comment: Im trying to push onto s2 whatever is popped from s1 if that makes sense?

Comment: Yep. So you need to assign the result of `s1.pop()` to a variable, then pass it to `s2.push()`. Or the shorter route, skipping the intermediate variable: `s2.push(s1.pop())`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just down to peek() now. Eclipse is throwing a red line?

Comment: Where is the red line? Did you make the change that the other answers suggested?

Comment: It looks like net.datastructures.Stack has a `top()` instead of a `peek()` method. You can use `top()`, or, since you're popping immediately after each peek, you can just pop into a variable and test whether that's null.

Comment: I think your right, yes, have made all the other changes. Eclipse is giving a red line for every peek() method :/ any ideas?

Comment: Ok, got it all sorted syntax wise. Now it seems that my method isn't correct, an emptystackexception is thrown when the compress method is called. I think my loops may be written incorrectly, is there anything you can see? Thanks for your time

Comment: That exception is thrown when you try to do `top()` or `pop()` on an empty Stack (one with no elements yet added). There is a method `isEmpty()` which you should use to check whether you can do a pop/top.

Comment: Also, your restacking lines are outside the loop (notice the placement of `}`).